# How to use async validator on submit with element plus in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, validation, element-plus

## Context description

I have a Vue 3 project and using element plus, I created a form with async validation. The code of validation function (Laravel precognition):

```
const validatePrecognitive = async (rule: InternalRuleItem, value: Value, callback: (error?: string | Error) => void) => {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!rule.field) {
            return;
        }

        precognitive.post('/events', computedFormData.value, {
            validate: [rule.field],
            onPrecognitionSuccess(response) {
                if (response.status === 204) {
                    callback();
                    resolve();
                }
            },
            onValidationError(response) {
                callback(new Error(response.data.message));
                reject();
            },
        });
    });
};
```

and I define the rules like this:

```
const rules: FormRules = reactive({
} as Partial<Record<string, Arrayable<FormItemRule>>>);

// dynamically set the rules for each input, because of same value for all rules
Object.keys(getSubmitShape()).forEach(key => {
    rules[key] = [{ asyncValidator: validatePrecognitiveDebounced, trigger: 'blur' }];
});
```

The *getSubmitShape()* funtion return Object with all form-item keys, that should be validated. So you can imagine it like:

```
const rules: FormRules = reactive({
    rules['name'] = [{ asyncValidator: validatePrecognitive, trigger: 'blur' }];
    rules['surname'] = [{ asyncValidator: validatePrecognitive, trigger: 'blur' }];
}
```

This works like a charm, when I write to inputs and switch between them. The errors would appear and dissappear correctly.

### Submit

When the form is submitted, I am calling `formEl.validate(...)` function, which should validate all the inputs. It works, **BUT**:

**for every rule item, one HTTP request is sent to server, because the validation method is called for each rule separately.**

### What I tried

I tried to implement debounce method, which would save the params from each previous function call and include that in next call, so in a last call, I would have all the inputs, rules and callbacks available. This works, when I try it while writing inputs to elements and switching them fast (triggering validation).

When on submit, it waits the debounce time for each rule. So the requests again go one by one with the delay of debounce time.

#### Any ideas, how I could make this in one request?

Thanks.